# Simple crossplatform xy plot in C++

Tags: c++, plot, cross-platform

I am trying to get a xy plot of 1024 point fft. I have fft output. I searched internet but everyone suggested the usage of third party plot libraries like gnuplot, koolplot etc. However, I want the program to work on different platforms. It should not be dependent on external sources (i.e. only standard libs).

I am not very experienced with plots (except Matlab). Can I write a simple xy-plot myself?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Pro-tip: **The main point behind the suggestion of using libraries is that it's to save time: development time.**

In other words, unless you have a **very good reason**, it's more _productive_ to learn and use someone else's library rather than roll your own. Any time could have been spent solving the problem would be "lost" reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thx for the tip. I know libraries are quicker options, but what I need is very simple, so using libraries will make the program size unnecessarily bulkier. I thought if it is simple enough, I will write it myself.

Comment: It's not a simple task. The fact that libraries exist (huge libraries), alone should tell you what you need. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to write your own, I suggest you take a look at [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). I have some limited experience using it for C/C++ projects that are cross-platform. There are of course other cross-platform GUI options out there. But if you have experience with C++, it should be pretty easy to get going.

Btw, there are some cross-platform graphing projects out there - [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) (using Qt)

Comment: Thx. I want to ask that if I write the program in Qt, do I have to run it on Qt as well?

Comment: No it's just a cross-platform GUI framework. You can write your C++ code once and compile for Windows, *nix, etc. If you are referring to their IDE, still the answer is no -- you only really care about the compiled code. It might be best to just think of Qt as a C++ library that you are referencing and it knows about GUI modules for many OS's.